# Update values in column based on value of same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

[image]

I need to write a UPDATE SQL query (using SQL Server 2012) for:

- If value COLUMN = AC5 AND InputParameterName = CD
  Then update value COLUMN = R1_123 OF ROW  WHERE InputParameterName = R AND same "bondcurescheduleid" from above condition
- If value COLUMN = AC6 AND InputParameterName = CD
  Then update value COLUMN = R2_546 OF ROW  WHERE InputParameterName = R for same bondcurescheduleid from above condition

Expected output:

[image]

Comment: Sample data (as formatted text) + expected results would help.

Comment: @DaleK added expected result

Comment: Looks like an image - you'll get a much better response if you add data as formatted text.

Comment: I have edited my answer now a third time.  Please stop changing your question.

Comment: I am really sorry

Comment: No issues, you are new to the site.  For future reference, for SQL questions a picture is worth a thousand words, quite literally.  Just showing us the input data, and the expected output, with only a two sentence description of the logic, already gets your question 90% of the way there.

Comment: Ok I will keep in mind @TimBiegeleisen. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try updating using a `CASE` expression along with exists logic to target the correct group of records:

```
UPDATE t1
SET
    t1.Value = CASE t2.Value WHEN 'AC5' THEN 'R1_123'
                             WHEN 'AC6' THEN 'R1_546' END
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t2.BondCureScheduleId = t1.BondCureScheduleId
WHERE
    t2.Value IN ('AC5', 'AC6') AND
    t1.InputParameterName = 'R' AND
    t2.InputParameterName = 'CD';
```

Comment: I want to update row of same bondcurescheduleID which have input parameter name as recipe

Comment: @anujduggal Please try the updated answer.  Your logic was not made very clear in your original question.

Comment: Sorry but it have some error in query. says "incorrect syntax near t1. Expecting set"